# How can I concatenate two Java streams while specifying specific logic for items that don't contain duplicates?

Tags: java, collections, java-8, java-stream

I have two maps that use the same object as keys. I want to merge these two streams by key. When a key exists in both maps, I want the resulting map to run a formula. When a key exists in a single map I want the value to be 0.

```
Map<MyKey, Integer> map1;
Map<MyKey, Integer> map2;

<Map<MyKey, Double> result =
    Stream.concat(map1.entrySet().stream(), map2.entrySet().stream())
        .collect(Collectors.toMap(
            Map.Entry::getKey, Map.Entry::getValue,
            (val1, val2) -> (val1 / (double)val2) * 12D));
```

This will use the formula if the key exists in both maps, but I need an easy way to set the values for keys that only existed in one of the two maps to 0D.

I can do this by doing set math and trying to calculate the inner-join of the two keySets, and then subtracting the inner-join result from the full outer join of them... but this is a lot of work that feels unnecessary.

Is there a better approach to this, or something I can easily do using the Streaming API?

Comment: Does it matter that the combination function isn't guaranteed to be applied to elements in the order that they were encountered?  12 * val1/val2 will be different depending on which values are bound to which variables

Comment: As far as a better approach, an AbstractMap could help.  You just need to provide the entry set for it, and that's not too hard, given the other maps.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here is a simple way, only stream the keys, and then looking up the values, and leaving the original maps unchanged.

```
Map<String, Double> result =
    Stream.concat(map1.keySet().stream(), map2.keySet().stream())
          .distinct()
          .collect(Collectors.toMap(k -> k, k -> map1.containsKey(k) && map2.containsKey(k)
                                                 ? map1.get(k) * 12d / map2.get(k) : 0d));
```

*Test*

```
Map<String, Integer> map1 = new HashMap<>();
Map<String, Integer> map2 = new HashMap<>();
map1.put("A", 1);
map1.put("B", 2);
map2.put("A", 3);
map2.put("C", 4);
// code above here
result.entrySet().forEach(System.out::println);
```

*Output*

```
A=4.0
B=0.0
C=0.0
```

Comment: Unlike mine, your answer works with `Map<?, Integer>` :)

Comment: Both answers were good. I went with this one though, so I'm going to accept this one.

Answer (score 4):

For this solution to work, your initial maps should be `Map<MyKey, Double>`.  I'll try to find another solution that will work if the values are initially `Integer`.

You don't even need streams for this!  You should simply be able to use `Map#replaceAll` to modify one of the `Map`s:

```
map1.replaceAll((k, v) -> map2.containsKey(k) ? 12D * v / map2.get(k) : 0D);
```

Now, you just need to add every key to `map1` that **is** in `map2`, but not `map1`:

```
map2.forEach((k, v) -> map1.putIfAbsent(k, 0D));
```

If you don't want to modify either of the `Map`s, then you should create a deep copy of `map1` first.

Comment: How does this "zero out" the entries that were only present in map1? I can see that for common keys, the formula is applied, and that keys unique to map2 are mapped to 0, but what about keys that were only in map1? Aren't they left unchanged here?

Comment: @JoshuaTaylor Since `replaceAll` essentially iterates over `map1`, it sets the value for keys not present in `map2` to `0` (see the conditional operator returning 0).

Comment: Ah, I was reading the older version of the answer before the replaceAll was added, that was just a single merge.

Comment: The `replaceAll` was actually the original version.  I changed it to `merge` because I thought I found a valid solution, but I was wrong, so I changed it back.  My apologies for the confusion!

Answer (score 2):

`Stream.concat` is not the right approach here, as you are throwing the elements of the two map together, creating the need to separate them afterward.

You can simplify this by directly doing the intended task of processing the intersection of the keys by applying your function and processing the other keys differently. E.g. when you stream over one map instead of the concatenation of two maps, you only have to check for the presence in the other map to either, apply the function or use zero. Then, the keys only present in the second map need to be put with zero in a second step:

```
Map<MyKey, Double> result = map1.entrySet().stream()
    .collect(Collectors.collectingAndThen(
        Collectors.toMap(Map.Entry::getKey, e -> {
            Integer val2 = map2.get(e.getKey());
            return val2==null? 0.0: e.getValue()*12.0/val2;
        }),
        m -> {
            Map<MyKey, Double> rMap = m.getClass()==HashMap.class? m: new HashMap<>(m);
            map2.keySet().forEach(key -> rMap.putIfAbsent(key, 0.0));
            return rMap;
        }));
```

This clearly suffers from the fact that Streams don’t offer convenience methods for processing map entries. Also, we have to deal with the unspecified map type for the second processing step. If we provided a map supplier, we also had to provide a merge function, making the code even more verbose.

The simpler solution is to use the Collection API rather than the Stream API:

```
Map<MyKey, Double> result = new HashMap<>(Math.max(map1.size(),map2.size()));
map2.forEach((key, value) -> result.put(key, map1.getOrDefault(key, 0)*12D/value));
map1.keySet().forEach(key -> result.putIfAbsent(key, 0.0));
```

This is clearly less verbose and potentially more efficient as it omits some of the Stream solution’s processing steps and provides the right initial capacity to the map. It utilizes the fact that the formula evaluates to the desired zero result if we use zero as default for the first map’s value for absent keys. If you want to use a different formula which doesn’t have this property or want to avoid the calculation for absent mappings, you’d have to use

```
Map<MyKey, Double> result = new HashMap<>(Math.max(map1.size(),map2.size()));
map2.forEach((key, value2) -> {
    Integer value1 = map1.get(key);
    result.put(key, value1 != null? value1*12D/value2: 0.0);
});
map1.keySet().forEach(key -> result.putIfAbsent(key, 0.0));
```

Comment: I sort of disagree in the capacity chosen here.. `Map<MyKey, Double> result = new HashMap<>(Math.max(map1.size(),map2.size()));` it should be something like `new HashMap<>(Math.max(map1.size(),map2.size()) / 0.75 + 1)`. `HashMap` takes number of *buckets* in it's constructor, while `CHM` number of entries

Comment: @Eugene it gets rounded up to the next power of two anyway. And its specification just says “capacity”, nothing about buckets or entries. I’m not going to make the formula unnecessary complicated just take care of implement details. It *may* sometimes still bear a capacity increase operation, but that’s still better than the repeated increase operation you might get with the default capacity.

Comment: in russian I would say "Хозяин-Барин", which is basically "your choice really", but in a way that makes you the correct one. Damn I wish there would be a saying like this in english or german (but I don't know german at all)